# Errores aplicación actualizada a symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony3

estoy pasando una aplicación desarrolada con symfony 2.8 a symfony 3.4, y me han ido saliendo errores. la autenticación me falla, y es debido al siguiente error tomado del archivo de logs:

```
security.INFO: Authentication request failed. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AuthenticationServiceException(code: 0): Unknown Entity namespace alias 'AppBundle'. at C:\\wamp64\\www\\sf3\\contenedores\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Authentication\\Provider\\DaoAuthenticationProvider.php:92, Doctrine\\ORM\\ORMException(code: 0): Unknown Entity namespace alias 'AppBundle'. at C:\\wamp64\\www\\sf3\\contenedores\\vendor\\doctrine\\orm\\lib\\Doctrine\\ORM\\ORMException.php:271)"} []
```

qué puedo hacer para solucionarlo??? imagino que hayan mucho  mas errores pero hasta que no logre arreglar este no puedo continuar.

Answer (score 0):

El error estaba en el archivo security.yml, me faltaba una directiva bajo la entrada `providers`, quedando la misma de la siguiente manera:

```
providers:
        userdb_provider:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:Usuario
                manager_name: default
```

de esta manera, se establece el nombre de la configuración del `entity_manager`establecido en el archivo `config.yml`